# Problems with Typescript typing

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with Typescript's type system. Can anybody help me with that, please?

Please have a look at [the demo](https://jsbin.com/mapesihezi/1/edit?html,js,output).

```
type Props = { [key: string]: any };

type Config<P extends Props> = {
  hint: string,
  main: (p: P) => string
}

function createDemo<P extends Props>(config: Config<P>): (p: P) => void {
  return (props: P) => {
     document.body.innerHTML +=
      `<div>[${config.hint} ${JSON.stringify(props)}] `
        + `${config.main(props)}</div>`;
  };
}

const demo = createDemo({
  hint: 'showing sum of two values',
  main: ({ x, y }) => x + y
});

demo({ x: 11, y: 22 });
demo({ xx: 11, yy: 22 }); // why do I not get
                          // a Typescript compile-time
                          // error here?!?
```

I would expect the last statement `demo({ xx: 11, yy: 22 })` to produce a compile-time error.
But the typescript transpiler seems to think it's fine.
Why? And how do I have to change the demo to be typesafe (means: making the last statement to cause indeed a compile-time error)?

[Edit: 1 hour later]

Maybe it helps a bit if I show you this code snippet which behaves exactly as I would have expected (at least if tsconfig.json is configured properly):

```
function createDemo<P>(action: ((data: P) => void)) {
    return (data: P) => {
        action(data);
    };
}

const demo = createDemo((data: { x: number; y: number }) => {
    document.body.innerText += JSON.stringify(data) + "\n";
});

demo({ x: 11, y: 22 });
demo({ xx: 11, yy: 22 }); // <- ERROR!!!
```

[Edit - 2 hours later]

Okay, thanks, after reading the answers below I've learned that things are working the way I would expect if I add the actual type signature at the "createDemo" invocation.

Nevertheless, frankly, I still do not get it completely why the type signature of

`const f = ({ x, y }) => ...;`

is interferred as

`const f = ({ x, y }: { x: any, y: any}) => ...`

while in my first example above the type signature of the main function

`main: ({ x, y }) => ...`

will be interferred as

`main: (p: {}) => ...`

instead of

`main: ({ x, y }: { x: any, y: any }) => ...`

Comment: Why do you expect to get an error there?

Comment: Andrew, please read the section "[Edit - 2 hours later]" above => that's why I thought the type inference result would be different.

Answer (score 0):

One bit of advice from looking at your code. I don't think you need P extends Props. The issue is this is Props is a dictionary of strings and your passing numbers.

As for your current demo not working this is because the main method within createDemo has no type signature for it's argument simply adding one will fix the problem arguments usually default to `any`.

```
const demo = createDemo({
  hint: 'showing sum of two values',
  main: ({ x, y }:{x:number, y:number}) => ""+x + y
});
```

Note the addition of ""+x+y is because you passed numbers and the result of main is expected to be a string.

Comment: “The issue is this is Props is a dictionary of strings and your passing numbers.” No, `Props` has keys of type `string` and values of type `any`, so `{xx: 11, yy: 22}` is conforming with `Props`.

Comment: Thomas, thanks, you're right, if I add the type signature in the main function then I got the compile error at the last statement.

Answer (score 0):

The function `createDemo` returns a function of type `({ [key: string]: any }) => void`, so that's what the type of `demo` will be. `demo` thus accepts an object with any string as a key, and any type as a value.

You could, for example, supply a type argument to `createDemo` to fix this:

```
const demo = createDemo<{x: any, y: any}>({
  hint: 'showing sum of two values',
  main: ({ x, y }) => x + y
});
```